# Class not found (PHP)

Tags: php, class, namespaces, include

I get a fatal error, the class THBS_AUTH_API is not found, the weird thing is i include it (correct file).

I tried require, require_once, include_once and is same problem.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'THBS_AUTH_API' not found in /srv/disk1/3203065/www/thos-host.com/content/client_areas/thos-host-client-area/admin_actions/thbs_settings.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk1/3203065/www/thos-host.com/client_area.php(1364): include() #1 {main} thrown in /srv/disk1/3203065/www/thos-host.com/content/client_areas/thos-host-client-area/admin_actions/thbs_settings.php on line 111
```

Class:

```
/* some comments */

namespace THBS_API;

@include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/install/".$config_file_path);

class THBS_API
{
    private const call_url = "https://YourWebsite.com/API/endsoftware.php";
    private const API_USER = "YourAPIUser";
    private const API_PASS = "YourAPIPass";

    public static function CMD_EXTERNAL($CMD = null, $GET_STATUS = 0, $ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS = null)
    {
        $base_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $fields = array(
            'API_USER' => urlencode(self::API_USER),
            'API_PASS' => urlencode(self::API_PASS),
            'CMD' => urlencode($CMD),
            'FROM' => urlencode($base_url),
            'ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS' => urlencode($ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS)
        );

        $fields_string = '';
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, self::call_url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if($GET_STATUS == 0) { return $response['response_data']; }
        else { return $response['response_status']; }
    }
}

class THBS_AUTH_API
{
    public static function CMD_AUTH($CMD = null, $GET_STATUS = 0, $ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS = null)
    {
        $base_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $fields = array(
            'API_USER' => urlencode($API_USER),
            'API_PASS' => urlencode($API_PASS),
            'TOKEN' => urlencode($API_USER."|".$API_PASS),
            'CMD' => urlencode($CMD),
            'FROM' => urlencode("From https://website.com"),
            'ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS' => urlencode($ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS)
        );

        $fields_string = '';
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://apiexample.com/API/private/THBS-API.php");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if($GET_STATUS == 0) { return $response['response_data']; }
        else { return $response['response_status']; }
    }
}
```

And, the file where i **include** this class file:

```
<?php
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/API/clientapi.php")) {
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/API/clientapi.php"); }
else { die('file not found (thbs-auth-api);'); }
?>
<div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>
```

So?
- File is correctly included.
- I use correct function to use the class;

Why? Why i get this error?

Comment: Is that _one_ file with _two_ namespaces? Because according to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php): "_The only code construct allowed before a namespace declaration is the declare statement, for defining encoding of a source file._"

Comment: You can't have 2 namespaces inside a single file.

Comment: uh,wait, i delete one

Comment: done, now i get same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your class under the namespace THBS_AUTH_API.
To use this namespace, add the line `namespace THBS_AUTH_API;` befor you call the class.

or change

```
<div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>
```

to

```
<div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_AUTH_API\THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>
```

**UPDATE**
Like in the comments stated above you can only have one namespace for one file. Since you deleted the second "namespace THBS_AUTH_API;" add this line at the top in thbs_settings.php:

```
namespace THBS_API;
```

or change

```
<div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>
```

to

```
<div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_API\THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /srv/disk1/3203065/www/thos-host.com/content/client_areas/thos-host-client-area/admin_actions/thbs_settings.php on line 3`

Comment: Screenshot with code:  https://prnt.sc/qzpvta

Comment: deleted one namespace because i can't use 2 in same file

Comment: @Thos-Host I tested your code, it works fine with one or the other change described above. :)

Comment: i deleted namespace, now i get sane problem

Comment: Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/qzq9f0

Comment: What namespace exactly did you delete?

Comment: namespace THBS_AUTH_API;

Comment: OK then "namespace THBS_API;" is the first line in clientapi.php, rigth? Then use this: <div class="licensecard" id="license">License key: <?php echo THBS_API\THBS_AUTH_API::CMD_AUTH("LICENSE_KEY", 1); ?></div>